# How to get the ids of nested array once the condition is met?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've a nested array, once the condition is met, it should give all the parent ids e.g. I've a data array, in which I should match the

- getParentIds(data, 182, []);

  - result: [96, 182];
- getParentIds(data, 174, []);

  - result: [109 , 219, 76 ,174];

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 96,
  "name": "test1",
  "items": [{
    "id": 181,
    "name": "Yes",
    "items": []
  }, {
    "id": 182,
    "name": "No",
    "items": []
  }]
}, {
  "id": 109,
  "name": "Test5",
  "items": [{
    "id": 219,
    "name": "opt2",
    "items": [{
      "id": 76,
      "name": "test3",
      "items": [{
        "id": 173,
        "name": "Yes",
        "items": []
      }, {
        "id": 174,
        "name": "No",
        "items": [{
          "id": 100,
          "name": "test2",
          "items": [{
            "id": 189,
            "name": "Yes",
            "items": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 224,
    "name": "opt3",
    "items": []
  }]
}];


function getParentIds(data, id, parentIds) {
  if (!parentIds) {
    parentIds = [];
  }
  data.map(function(item) {
    if (item.id === id) {
      parentIds.push(item.id);
      return parentIds;
    } else if (item.items.length === 0) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      return getParentIds(item.items, id, parentIds);
    }
  });
}

console.log("Array list: " + getParentIds(data, 182, []));
```

Could you give me any suggestion on this?

Comment: *js:71 Uncaught ReferenceError: getParentDetails is not defined*

Comment: Try something like post order traversal

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) Return a new version of the array, based on the callback function, you probably need [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and `getParentIds()` should return a value, so after the `foreach()` loop, you should `return parentIds;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a cool problem. It took me more than I expected to solve it, but here's a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) implementation:

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 96,
  "name": "test1",
  "items": [{
    "id": 181,
    "name": "Yes",
    "items": []
  }, {
    "id": 182,
    "name": "No",
    "items": []
  }]
}, {
  "id": 109,
  "name": "Test5",
  "items": [{
    "id": 219,
    "name": "opt2",
    "items": [{
      "id": 76,
      "name": "test3",
      "items": [{
        "id": 173,
        "name": "Yes",
        "items": []
      }, {
        "id": 174,
        "name": "No",
        "items": [{
          "id": 100,
          "name": "test2",
          "items": [{
            "id": 189,
            "name": "Yes",
            "items": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 224,
    "name": "opt3",
    "items": []
  }]
}];


function parentsOf( arr, id, parents){
    if (parents.length)
        return parents;
    // I use for(;;) instead of map() because I need the return to exit the loop
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if ( arr[i].id == id){
             //push the current element at the front of the parents array
             parents.unshift( arr[i].id );
             return parents;
        };
        if ( arr[i].items ){
            parents = parentsOf(arr[i].items, id, parents);
            // if the parents array has any elements in it it means we found the child
            if (parents.length){
                parents.unshift(arr[i].id);
                return parents;
            }
        }
    }
    return parents;
}

console.log("Array list for 182: " + parentsOf(data, 182, []));
console.log("Array list for 174: " + parentsOf(data, 174, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

If this task will be done repeatedly it would be a clever approach first to flatten the nested array into a hash table where the keys would be id properties. While flattening you can add a parents property to the objects. Then the search would be as simple and fast as accessing an object property on the hash table. The following demonstrates the mentioned approach.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 96,
  "name": "test1",
  "items": [{
    "id": 181,
    "name": "Yes",
    "items": []
  }, {
    "id": 182,
    "name": "No",
    "items": []
  }]
}, {
  "id": 109,
  "name": "Test5",
  "items": [{
    "id": 219,
    "name": "opt2",
    "items": [{
      "id": 76,
      "name": "test3",
      "items": [{
        "id": 173,
        "name": "Yes",
        "items": []
      }, {
        "id": 174,
        "name": "No",
        "items": [{
          "id": 100,
          "name": "test2",
          "items": [{
            "id": 189,
            "name": "Yes",
            "items": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 224,
    "name": "opt3",
    "items": []
  }]
}],

getParents = (ar, id) => {var fData = (a, pid, pin) => a.reduce((p,c) => {c.parents = pid.concat();
                                                                          p[c.id] = c;
                                                                          c.items.length && fData(c.items, pid.concat(c.id), p);
                                                                          return p;
                                                                         }, pin);
                          return fData(ar,[],{})[id].parents;
                         }; //so much for getParents

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(getParents(data, 189), null, 2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Hi Redu, I want to try your approach to get my result. But the code is not providing the correct result. It iterate all the id. I believe, the condition is missing to check the parent id. Can you help me to get the exact output.
Appreciate your support!

Comment: @Premkumar Jayaseelan: OK fixed.. even got somewhat shorter.

Comment: Hi @Redu, Thank you so much for the immediate solution. +1